# Show that the canonical inclusion $ L^\infty → L^1 $ is continuous but not compact. (a problem in real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

Would you mind giving some hints (not the whole solution) to me?

> **Problem**: Consider the space $ L^p = L^p(0, 1),$ with $ p ∈ [1, ∞].$ Show that the canonical inclusion
>   $ L^\infty → L^1 $ 
>   is continuous but not compact.
>
> Is it possible to find $ p, q ∈ [1, ∞] $ with $p < q$ such that the inclusion $L^q \to L^p$ is compact?

Comment: Ok, a hint: if you figure out the first part then, for the second part, note that the composition $f \circ g$ with $f$ compact and $g$ continuous is compact.

Comment: Another hint: in order to show a linear map of B- Space from $Y$ into $X$ is not compact it is sufficient to find a sequence $y_n$ in the unit sphere of $Y$ the image of which has no subsequence which is Cauchy. For the spaces under consideration you need to find a constant $c>0$ and sequence of functions $f_n:(0,1)\rightarrow [-1,1]$ such that for each pair $n,m$ the difference $|f_n-f_m|$ has volume $>c$ below it's graph. Try a sequence of funcions $f_n$ which equals $1$ for $x\in [i/2^n, (i+1)/2^n]$ ($i$ even) and $-1 $ elsewhere. If that does not work some simple modification should work.

Comment: Are you familiar with some properties of the Fourier basis $(e_n)_n$ with $e_n(x) = e^{2\pi i n x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a set $C$ is compact in $\mathbb L^p(0,1)$, then 
  $$\lim_{h\to 0}\sup_{f\in C}     \int_{(0,1)\cap (h,1-h) } \left\lvert f(x+h)-f(x)\right\rvert^p\mathrm dx=0.            $$

In order to disprove compactness, find for any $n$ a set $A_n$ such that 
$$ \int_{\left (0,1-2^{-n}\right)   } \left\lvert\mathbf 1_{A_n}  \left (x+2^{-n}  \right)-\mathbf 1_{A_n}(x)\right\rvert^p\mathrm dx\geqslant 1/2.$$
For example, choose $A_n$ as a union of $2^{n-1}$ intervals of length $2^{-n}$, with a gap of $2^{-n}$  between them.